# How to remove brackets from nested array using python

Tags: python

I am trying remove brackets from the nested array.
Thank you for helping me in advance..

this is input data

```
{
"th":[ [ "aa"],["bb"]]
}
```

expected output is

```
{
"th":["aa","bb"]
}
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not elegant but simple:

```
data={
    "th":[ [ "aa"],["bb"]]
     }
data["th_mod"]=[element[0] for element in data["th"]]
data
```

Gives

`{'th': [['aa'], ['bb']], 'th_mod': ['aa', 'bb']}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to accomplish this:

```
import itertools
data["th_mod"] = itertools.chain.from_iterable(data["th"])
```

this can be done also using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
equivalent to this code:

```
import itertools
data["th_mod"] = itertools.chain(*data["th"])
```

here is the output:

```
>>> data
{"th":[["aa"],["bb"]],"th_mod":["aa","bb"]}
```